# Problemas para calcular o maior int primo em C

Tags: c

Olá.

Estou tentando calcular o maior número primo que caiba em uma variável int. A minha ideia foi começar pelo maior int, e ir checando em ordem decrescente até encontrar o primeiro número primo. Quando tento executar o programa recebo a mensagem: "maiorprimo.exe parou de funcionar. O Windows está verificando uma solução para o problema."

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
    int primo=0;
    int num=INT_MAX;
    for(num; num>0; num--){
        primo=ePrimo(num);
        if(primo==1){
            printf("%d eh primo" ,num);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int ePrimo(int n){
    int i;
    int cont;
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
        if(n%i==0){
            cont++;
        }
    }
    if(cont==2)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na função `main()` chamas a funçáo `ePrimo()` com o valor `INT_MAX`.

Na função `ePrimo()` o teu ciclo

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) { /* ... */ }
```

é um ciclo infinito.

`i` é **sempre** menor ou igual a `INT_MAX`.

Sugestão: começa a verificação em `2` (em vez de `0`) e vai até à raiz quadrada de `n`. Se apanhares um divisor, devolve logo `0` sem calcular outros divisores.

Comment: Consegui! Muito obrigado. Fiz o algoritmo testando somente até a raiz quadrada, e um loop fora da função testando primeiro o INT_MAX e decrementando até achar o primeiro primo.